# AMPL loops and omitting variables

Tags: syntax, iteration, ampl

Have started using ampl recently and have run into a hiccup regarding iteration  and indexing.

I have the following model script:

```
set NUTR;
set FOOD;

param Cost {FOOD} > 0; #Costs pr. gramm

param f_min {FOOD} >=0;
param f_max {j in FOOD} >= f_min[j];

param n_min {NUTR} >=0;
param n_max {i in NUTR} >= n_min[i];

param amount {NUTR,FOOD} >= 0; #amount nutrients pr. gramm

var Purchase {j in FOOD} >= f_min[j], <= f_max[j];

minimize Total_cost: sum{j in FOOD} Cost[j] * Purchase[j];
s.t. Intake {i in NUTR}: n_min[i] <= sum {j in FOOD} amount[i,j] *  
Purchase[j] <= n_max[i]; 

data;

set NUTR := PRT CRB FAT KCAL;
set FOOD := CD VL HM SLM TN MCR EGG BN PS FSL PEN RC ORG PT ON AVC CLF CBG ALM TMT OLV MLK ;
```

The model runs fine with the dataset, but my question is:
Is it possible to create a loop giving an optimal solution, omitting one product from the set FOOD at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily in a .run by looping over FOOD and then using the set difference operator to define the set "everything from FOOD except this one element". This should give you the general idea:

```
model;
set FOOD;
data; 
set FOOD := CD VL HM SLM TN MCR EGG BN PS FSL PEN RC ORG PT ON AVC CLF CBG ALM TMT OLV MLK ;

for{f in FOOD}{
    printf "\nThe set Food minus %s is:", f;
    display (FOOD diff {f});
    # replace with your model and solve commands, indexing over "FOOD diff {f}". 
}
```